# jQuery not loading the project in the slideshow container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

When an image is clicked the project text seems to appear but the header is duplicated and the 'Back to Portofolio' button and header buttons don't appear to work.

If you return to the 'Portfolio' page the project text is still appearing.

http://www.janinejauvel.com/test/

**html**

```
<li style="height:393px;" data-src="http://www.janinejauvel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/editorial-1-rwd-magazine.png">
<span class="cover" style="width:308px;height:0px;background-image:url('http://www.janinejauvel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/bg-white.png')"></span>
<hgroup style="width:308px;height:393px;background-image:url('http://www.janinejauvel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/bg-white.png')" data-project="test/dirty-fashion">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Editorial I</h3>
                            <span class="dash">&mdash;</span>
                            <p>RWD Magazine</p>
                        </div>
                    </hgroup>
                </li>
```

**script.js**

```
// load the project into the slideshow container div
                $('#slideshow-container').load('' + $hgroup.attr('data-project'), function() {
                    // bind slideshow
                        slideshow.render();
                        $('section#work').css('margin-top', '0px');
                });

            });


$(document).ready(function() {

    hattie.init();
    hattie.clickEvents();
    hattie.loadImages();

});

$(window).resize(function() {

    // get the currently active project, if there is one

    if ($('#slideshow').length > 0) {


        var activeProject   = $('#slideshow').attr('class');

        // trigger click
        $('hgroup[data-project="'+ activeProject + '"]').trigger('click');

    }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
$('#slideshow-container').load('' + $hgroup.attr('data-project'), function() {
```

To:

```
$('#slideshow-container').load('' + $hgroup.attr('data-project') + ' #content', function() {
```

This will load the content div of the url in $hgroup.attr('data-project').

Comment: Thank you! That worked. It seems that if you then go back to 'Portfolio' the project content is still visible to the left of the website frame. Any ideas how I can hide this?

Comment: Could simply do a $('#slideshow-container').html(''); to reset the html to nothing.

Comment: @user1096057 Guessing you could not figure it out on your own via my hints below with the same answer using page fragments. wowzers

Comment: Apologies! I'm relatively new to all of this stuff. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call load, you are loading an entire HTML page into that div that contains that header element.

Look at what is on the page you are loading: http://www.janinejauvel.com/test/dirty-fashion

You just want the content. Look into loading [page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments).

Comment: How can I change that to stop doing it?

Comment: How do I tell it to only load the content?